# Invoke a twilio function without Studio Flow

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I cannot seem to figure out how to call a Twilio function correctly. I tried calling it by passing data via POST:

```
url = "https://xxxx-dev.twil.io/voicemail" 
data = {'event': {'id': '00141',
                  'RecordingUrl': 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ssssss/Recordings/xxxxxxx.mp3',
                  'From': '+12xxxxxxxxx',
                  'textTranslation': 'something here'}}
requests.post(url, data=data)
```

It doesn't seem to work. It returns 500 because it does not find the event object or the context object.
How do I pass event, context, callback when calling a function directly?

Comment: can you include the code or command with your Twilio Function URL?

Comment: You mean include url address into the post request? I will. I also found the solution for this issue and I will post the solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was sending the data incorrectly.
You also don't need to include context nor callback, those are provided by twilio. You need to send only data as json to that endpoint.

```
url = "https://xxxx-dev.twil.io/voicemail" 
data = {'id': '00141',
        'RecordingUrl': 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ssssss/Recordings/xxxxxxx.mp3',
        'From': '+12xxxxxxxxx',
        'textTranslation': 'something here'}
requests.post(url, json=data)
```